# Mod_rewrite doesn't work properly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting a (very) simple mod_rewrite to work.

Here's my code...

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine on

#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^libs/jquery.html$ libs/loader.php [L]
```

Basically I'm trying to get mydomain.com/libs/jquery.html to pull up the page libs/loader.php

This is my entire .htaccess file - what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's it, but I noticed that you wrote 'on' instead of 'On'.

Also, are there maybe query params at work so your regex does not match?

Comment: Unfortunately changing to "On" doesn't do anything. Also, there's no URL params (not yet anyway, I want to get this basic version working before I venture into anything else)